# Google Colab does not display properly

Tags: google-colaboratory

After using Google Colab a short period, buttons start displaying text instead of their original appearance.

Before: [enter image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUVGB.png)

After using it for a while, error shows up: [enter image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCpU6.png)

What i tried:

- Clear browser cached cookies
- Uncheck the options for "Enable JavaScript source maps" and "Enable CSS source maps"

And I use no fonts.

Why this happening and how to solve it?

Thanks.